# what is the time complexity of this program??Big-O-notation for this program?

Tags: python, big-o

What is the time complexity and Big-O notation for this code?

```
def rot(a,n):
    for i in range(n-1):
        temp=a[i]
        a[i]=a[i+1]
        a[i+1]=temp
    return a
n=int(input())

x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for i in range(n):
    x=rot(x,7)
    print(x)
```

Comment: O(n^2) what's so difficult about the same?

Comment: seems to be a trick question. That's what's a little difficult about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is O(n)

You have two nested for loops, which might indicate it's `O(n**2)`, but the second for loop does not depend on the variable n. it depends on x and 7, which both do not depend on n.

The parameter of the function rot is called `n`, but its passed value is always  `7`, thus not depending on n.

So if you multiply n by 2 the amount of instructions to execute is about twice as much.